# Importing Notes database from Sierra backup to High Sierra

Tags: icloud, macos, backup

I went to backup my notes from my old Mac (running macOS Sierra) onto an external hard drive (was selling quickly and didn't have time to perform a full Time Machine backup). All I want is my Notes! The new High Sierra can't open them.

I tried to put them back from the external hardrive to  ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/ (using this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoJAjACycPE) 
but that didn't work for me. These notes are notesv7.